# Redirecting from drop-down

Tags: javascript, jsp

I'm really really new to coding so here's my question.
How do I redirect to another page using JSP and Javascript? or Servlet? I don't understand a thing in Servlet that's why I use Javascript. When I choose any of the options and click submit, nothing happens.

Here's my code:

JSP:

```
<form>
    <select id="module_id" name="module_id" />
        <option value="0" selected /></option>
        <option value="1" /> CD101 </option>
        <option value="2" /> CD102 </option>
        <option value="3" /> CD103 </option>
        <option value="4" /> CD104 </option>
        <option value="5" /> CD105 </option>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick ="myChoice();" />
    </select>
</form>
```

Javascript: (google-d)

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function myChoice(){
  var s = document.getElementById("module_id");
  var module_id = s.selectedIndex.value;

  if (module_id === 1)
      window.location = "response.jsp";
  if (module_id === 2)
      window.location = "http://www.google.com";
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
function myChoice(){
  var s = document.getElementById("module_id");
  var module_id = s.value;
  console.log(module_id );
  if (module_id === "1")
      alert("ok");
  if (module_id === 1)
      alert("not ok");
}
```

```html
<form>
    <select id="module_id" name="module_id" />
        <option value="0" selected /></option>
        <option value="1" /> CD101 </option>
        <option value="2" /> CD102 </option>
        <option value="3" /> CD103 </option>
        <option value="4" /> CD104 </option>
        <option value="5" /> CD105 </option>
        <input type="button" value="Submit" onclick ="myChoice();" />
    </select>
</form>
```

Replace this from your code:

```
function myChoice(){
      var s = document.getElementById("module_id");
      var module_id = s.value;//changed
    
      if (module_id === "1")//changed
          window.location.href = "response.jsp";
      if (module_id === "2")//changed
          window.location.href = "http://www.google.com";
    }
```

Explanation:

You are getting `string` type value and you were comparing with `int`, The  `===` operator compare the value as well  as type so that's why redirection was not happening.

For more you should read this awesome answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/359509/3143384.

And `selectedIndex` of javascript returns the index of selected option not its object reference.  so you have to user `option` or `value`. For more you can read [this](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_select_selectedindex.asp)
and
try [this example](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_option_index)

Comment: ohmygod, how could i miss that out.. and the s.value. thank you very much sir!!!!!

Comment: Use `window.location.href = ...`, for some browsers simply `window.location = ...` won't work

Comment: @hi_chua any time :)